# 100 Days of Code - 37 - Love Calculator - What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python

Newbie here and I've taken a shot at a Love Calculator using the logic in my brain and here is what I got prior to some learning tweaks from the 100 Days of Code course.  I'm stumped as to why I'm getting '21' as my answer if I used the teacher's provided instructional answers of 'Angela Yu' and 'Jack Bauer' as input, as opposed to 53, the correct answer.

Would love some guidance related to the logic.  Thanks!

```
name1_lower = name1.lower()
name2_lower = name2.lower()

t_count = name1_lower.count("t")
r_count = name1_lower.count("r")
u_count = name1_lower.count("u")
e_count = name1_lower.count("e")
true_count = t_count + r_count + u_count + e_count

l_count = name2_lower.count("l")
o_count = name2_lower.count("o")
v_count = name2_lower.count("v")
e2_count = name2_lower.count("e")
love_count = l_count + o_count + v_count + e2_count

total_count = int(str(true_count) + str(love_count))

#I learned to convert the above to string, and then back to integer 
# from Dr. Yu, didn't have this initially
# perhaps I need to do the same above to true_count and love_count?

if total_count < 10 or total_count > 90:
    print(f"Your score is {total_count}, you go together like coke and mentos.")
elif total_count >= 40 and total_count <= 50:
    print(f"Your score is {total_count}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {total_count}.")
```

Comment: You need to give self sufficient context, mentioning another website is not sufficient. We have no clue what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I think your print statements are wrongly formated. See my answer below.

Comment: Would you care to explain why you think you should get an answer of 53, from what i can see 21 is correct. By applying "Angela Yu" as name 1 and counting the instances of either [t,r,u,e] we find 1 u and 1 e giving a total of 2, then "Jack Bauer" for [l,o,v,e] has only 1 e in common, so returns a 1, then converting each number to a string and adding the strings returns 21 - I wouldn't advise converting from string to integer, it's masking what's actually happening, unless this is your desired result, otherwise you'd get an  answer of 3.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your feedback.  Liam I think you got me going down the path and I realized the instructor was asking me to take both names and check both of them against the word TRUE and LOVE, not independtly.  You showing me that my current method returned 21 and why really helped.

Comment: no problem Aara, i've provided an example code iterating through both words in the answers, feel free to upvote or mark as answered if you found it helpful. Or ask more questions if you don't understand some part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is for the day 3 exercise of out of 100 days course https://www.udemy.com/course/100-days-of-code/ which I am also taking.
This is an excellent Python course, I am just at day 3 as well.

The concept of counting is from here https://www.buzzfeed.com/ariannarebolini/what-are-the-chances-your-crush-is-actually-your-true-love

The below answer is good, but we haven't covered `for` loops yet.

```
for name in [name1_lower, name2_lower]:
    for letter in ["t","r","u","e"]:
        true_count += name.count(letter)
    for letter in ["l","o","v","e"]:    
        love_count += name.count(letter)
```

Below is my code, which works:

```
print("Welcome to the Love Calculator!")
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

name1 = name1.lower()
name2 = name2.lower()

name1_t = name1.count('t')
name1_r = name1.count('r')
name1_u = name1.count('u')
name1_e = name1.count('e')

name2_t = name2.count('t')
name2_r = name2.count('r')
name2_u = name2.count('u')
name2_e = name2.count('e')

name1_l = name1.count('l')
name1_o = name1.count('o')
name1_v = name1.count('v')
name1_e = name1.count('e')

name2_l = name2.count('l')
name2_o = name2.count('o')
name2_v = name2.count('v')
name2_e = name2.count('e')

true_score = name1_t + name1_r + name1_u + name1_e + name2_t + name2_r + 
name2_u + name2_e
love_score = name1_l + name1_o + name1_v + name1_e + name2_l + name2_o + 
name2_v + name2_e 

total_score = true_score * 10 + love_score


if total_score < 10 or total_score > 90:
    print(f"Your score is {total_score}, you go together like coke and 
mentos.")

elif total_score > 40 and total_score < 50:
    print(f"Your score is {total_score}, you are alright together.")

else:
    print(f"Your score is {total_score}.")
```

Just looked at instructor's code. She used the below which is smart to save some lines of code. Instead of check for name 1 and name 2 separately, she concatenate them as a string:

```
combined string =name1 + name2
```

Also, she converted the `score` to `str` to concatenate and then back to type `int` in order to compare, while I use:

```
total_score = true_score * 10 + love_score
```

Thus, there is no need to change to `str` then back to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

First to all, remove the f on the print statement and it will compile. Do like this:

```
if total_count < 10 or total_count > 90:
    print("Your score is {total_count}, you go together like coke and mentos.")
elif total_count >= 40 and total_count <= 50:
    print("Your score is {total_count}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print("Your score is {total_count}.")
```

.count("A") returns the number of occurrences of the character "A" on a string. So you need to add these counts without converting them to string.
total_count =true_count + love_count

Additionally, I think you need to find true and love count on each name, which you are not doing.

Comment: It also change completely the meaning of the strings ;) Those are called f-strings

Answer (score 1):

This may get the result you're looking for, instead of iterating through a single name for each word apply both names to each word.

```
name1 = "Angela Yu"
name2 = "Jack Bauer"
name1_lower = name1.lower()
name2_lower = name2.lower()
true_count, love_count = 0, 0
for name in [name1_lower, name2_lower]:
    for letter in ["t","r","u","e"]:
        true_count += name.count(letter)
    for letter in ["l","o","v","e"]:    
        love_count += name.count(letter)
total_count = int(str(true_count) + str(love_count))
if total_count < 10 or total_count > 90:
    print(f"Your score is {total_count}, you go together like coke and mentos.")
elif total_count >= 40 and total_count <= 50:
    print(f"Your score is {total_count}, you are alright together.")
else:
    print(f"Your score is {total_count}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

name1 = "Angela Yu"
name2 = "Jack Bauer"

T occurs 0 times
R occurs 1 time
U occurs 2 times
E occurs 2 times

Total = 5

L occurs 1 time
O occurs 0 times
V occurs 0 times
E occurs 2 times

Total = 3

Love Score = 53

In your solution provided, you are calculating how often letters “true” appear for Angela and “love” appear for Jack which would correctly give you 21. Instead you should calculate how often letters “true” and “love” appear across both names then combine the two numbers to form 53 as detailed above.